# Implementing Google Analytics through GoDaddy/Website Tonight

Tags: google, analytics, godaddy

Is there a way to implement Analytics with GoDaddy's "Website Tonight?" Obviously GoDaddy wants you to sell you their analytics package, but this is what the client wants. I don't see any way to access the head of the page, and Google isn't recognizing analytics code placed in the body. I've scoured the Internet and all I can find is outdated information and things like this http://community.godaddy.com/help/2996 which have been no help. Thanks for your time and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Version v4 and v7 of Website Tonight allow adding a **script** tag within the **head** tag, in page properties.

With v6 however just add a **script** block anywhere on the page, and paste the Google Analytics code in.  As @Toby said, it works fine from the **body**.  I just add the **script** block below the last text box: works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics can be executed from the body, in fact some people recommend it.

When placed in the body what happens when you view the source of the page, could GoDaddy be stripping out JavaScript?